# Understanding of shell sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I have a couple of questions I couldn't find online regarding Shell sort with Shell's gap.

```
public static void shell(int[] a) {
    int increment = a.length / 2;
    while (increment > 0) {
        for (int i = increment; i < a.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int temp = a[i];
            while (j >= increment && a[j - increment] > temp) {
                a[j] = a[j - increment];
                j = j - increment;
            }
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        if (increment == 2) {
            increment = 1;
        } else {
            increment *= (5.0 / 11);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I found online, but I don't really understand the last else statement. What does 5.0/11 represent?
Also I need to analyse the complexity of the algorithm, though I'm receiving pretty perplexing results:

[image: results]

It seems that it is O(n) either best and worst cases. Are these results legit?

Comment: The floating point number 5.0 being divided by 11. Do the math on a calculator.

Comment: The `shell` tag should be removed from this question.

Comment: What does the graph represent? Could you at least label the axes? If it's time and number of items sorted, then I'm suspicious. It shows your algorithm to be linear, which is ... unlikely. How did you generate this graph?

Answer (score 0):

5.0/11 is actually used to get the half of the increment. Anything <0.5 and >0.45 will work to obtain the half of the value in round figures.